# command similar to grep, in windows

Tags: grep, clearcase, findstr

I got the command findstr

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr /C:"US-100"
```

which giving me the logs below

> App.java@@\main\6,US-100
>       target@@\main\0,target@@\main,target@@,US-1001
>       target@@\main\1,US-1001
>       newfilecreated.txt@@\main\1,US-1001
>       newfilecreated.txt@@\main\0,newfilecreated.txt@@\main,newfilecreated.txt@@,US-1001
>       anotherfile.txt@@\main\1,US-1001
>       anotherfile.txt@@\main\0,anotherfile.txt@@\main,anotherfile.txt@@,US-1001
>       akshay.txt@@\main\1,US-1001
>       akshay.txt@@\main\0,akshay.txt@@\main,akshay.txt@@,US-1001

which is giving me the logs having comments US-1001 also but I want the logs specifically which has comment equals US-100 only not US-1001 logs

Comment: `findstr` has a `/V` option which works like `grep -v`. So `cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr /C:"US-100" | findstr /V "US-1001"`. See `findstr/?`.

Comment: You can also get grep for windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), you could use a regexp

```
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr /R "US-100$"
# or
cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr /R ".*US-100$"
```

The '`$`' [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) forces the line to ends with `US-100`.

Comment: little bit correction is needed /R does not have :(colon) working command is _cleartool lshistory -fmt "%n,%c" |findstr /R "US-100$"_